# Fluid Dynamic CSS - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I am wondering if there is way, to mark a MAX and a MIN value depending on the max Width of the browser window and min Width of the browser window, and have it dynamically change that MAX and MIN value between that set range?

Example:

I have a button "button" outside a div "divA" (it is part of another div "divB", that lies outside the div being discussed), and I want this button "button" to lie at the bottom right corner of this initial div "divA".

Now, I can get the button to lie at the bottom right corner when the browser window is at is absolute minimum, and at the absolute maximum, but the in between is a bit sporadic since I'm positioning the button absolutely, and then changing the bottom percentage on the two media widths.

Is there a a known javascript or jquery that would allow me to do this?

**example CSS:**

```
#divA{
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
}

#divB{
 width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

#button{
 position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
   #button{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100%;   
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px){
   #button{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 250%;   
   }
}
```

**example HTML:**

```
<div id="divA"></div>
<div id="divB"><button>CLICK ME</button></div>
```

Comment: In your posted code, the two media queries are identic

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry about that... thanks for the heads up

Comment: I hope I'm not oversimplifying, but...it basically sounds like you just want for your button to be at the *bottom* of divA, regardless of how high divA is. Am I wrong? You really don't need media queries for that.

Comment: the button in the HTML lives inside divB.  I will modify the code once more.

Answer (score 0):

demo -http://jsfiddle.net/ogjhef7c/1/

you are setting `bottom` to by 250% 100% try changing the value, `@media` works find try resizing the`attached fiddle`height`

```
@media screen and (max-height: 300px) {
    #button {
        bottom: 0px;
        background: red;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 100px) {
    #button {
        bottom: 0px;
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: there was a mistake in my original code. The original max-width was 768, but the second width was supposed to be 400px.  I am not looking to change the color of the background.